# Dynamically redirect back to the same url after requesting

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

How do we dynamically redirect back to the same page after delete request.

---

**Request link:**
The request link which appears in many pages.

```
<a href="/delete/id">delete</a>
```

**route.js**

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res, next) {
      // deleting logic here
      res.redirect('/to/requesting/page');
});
```

where `/to/resquesting/page` is the url to the page that has requested deletion:

- If `/delete/:id` has been requested from Homepage, we would call `res.redirect('/home');`
- If `/delete/:id` has been requested from Product, we would call `res.redirect('/product);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
res.redirect('back');
```

It is based on `req.get('Referrer')`
If response is cached in browser you can clear cache with headers:

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
res.redirect('back');
```

Comment: Thank you, redirect('back') solved my problem. Why would we want to set header like in your post?

Comment: Couse when you go back to previous url you will get status 304. And in some cases you will get previous content.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I experimented with or without set header give me the same result when I click back.

Comment: You can read more for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352241/reload-a-page-after-res-redirectback-in-route/20389831 .